# Calcular duração em php

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou com um outro probleminha e preciso da ajuda de alguém.
O sistema que estou fazendo é para uma escola e eu preciso que meu sistema calcule a duração que cada aluno teve dentro das aulas, para isso, eu sei que preciso usar o comando (SUM) dentro do meu select, mais e depois? 
O resultado final de que eu preciso, é mostrar em um echo"" todas as horas que este aluno teve estudando e assim fazer um controle de pacotes por exemplo, onde cada aluno pode ter somente um pacote de 8 horas, a cada vez que o aluno participa da aula, vai somar esses valores e diminuir dentro da minha tabela pacote, como eu faço isso trabalhando com duração de tempo em PHP?

Tudo que eu tenho é esse código:

```
<?php
      $pesquisa_horas_dadas = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(horas_dadas) FROM pacotes");
    while($sum = mysql_fetch_array($pesquisa_horas_dadas)){
        $soma_horas_dadas = $sum['horas_dadas'];
            }

    echo $soma_horas_dadas; echo"</br>";    
    $seleciona_duracao = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Duracao) FROM Assiste"); 
    $resultset = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(Duracao) as Duracao FROM Assiste'); 
    $linha= mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset); 
    $soma = $linha['Duracao'];

    echo $soma; echo"</br>";

    $soma01 = "01:23";

    $totalHora = $soma / 3600; 

    function converterHora($soma){
        $hora = sprintf("%02s",floor($soma / (60*60)));
        $minuto = ($soma01 % (60*60));
        $soma = sprintf("%02s",floor ($soma / 60 ));
        $soma = ($soma % 60);
        $hora_minuto = $hora.":".$minuto;
        return $hora_minuto;
                        }
       $hora = converterHora($segundosTotal);

      echo $hora;   

                        ?>
```

Exemplo MYSQL:

[image: Exemplos das tabelas Alunos, Pacotes e Assiste]

Nesta tabela, a duração de cada aula eu consegui fazer normalmente, está retornando tudo certinho no banco de dados, O meu problema é pegar os dados deste campo (Duracao) colocar em uma variável e subtrair dentro do campo (horas_rest) do id de numero 22 na tabela pacotes, já que cada pacote somente terá um aluno 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não consegui entender! Não consegue subtrair valores de tempo?

Comment: Se entendi direito, o seu erro acontece só no PHP. No banco de dados está funcionando correto. É isso?

Comment: Não existe erro, eu não consigo fazer

Comment: Eu quero somar tudo que tem dentro do campo (duracao) da tabela Assiste  e subtrair dentro do campo (horas_dadas) na tabela PHP

Comment: Exemplo:
Aluno José, tal ID 3 assistiu a aula 2 durante 1 hora e 20 minutos e a aula 3 durante 1 hora e 32 minutos, o mesmo aluno tem o pacote de numero 22 que comprou com um limite de 8 horas, só quero que o sistema some as horas assistidas e subtraia no valor de horas dadas dentro da tabela pacotes, então, na table pacote, ele tem 8 horas de limite de aula e 0 horas até o momento de horas assistidas, quero que dentro do campo mostre o valor de 2 horas e 52 minutos (02:52) dentro do campo (horas_dadas) da tabela pacotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pelo que eu entendi**

*(pegar os dados deste campo "Duracao" colocar em uma variável e subtrair dentro do campo "horas_rest" do id de numero 22 na tabela pacotes)*

**isso pode ser feito da seguinte maneira:**

```
$Horas_rest = '8';  //select de Horas_rest
$soma = '1:07';  //select da soma do campo Duracao da tabela assiste

if (strpos($Horas_rest, ":")){
    $hora1 = explode(":",$Horas_rest);
    $min_hora1 = ($hora1[0] * 3600) + ($hora1[1] * 60);
}else{
    $min_hora1 = ($Horas_rest * 3600);
}

if (strpos($soma, ":")){
    $hora2 = explode(":",$soma);
    $min_hora2 = ($hora2[0] * 3600) + ($hora2[1] * 60);
}else{
    $min_hora2 = ($soma * 3600);
}


$resultado = $min_hora1 - $min_hora2;

$hora = floor($resultado / 3600);

$resultado = $resultado - ($hora * 3600);

$min = floor($resultado / 60)/10;

$min=str_replace(".","",$min);

if(strlen($min)==1){
    $min=$min."0";
}

$result=$hora.":".$min;

  //UPDATE Pacotes SET Horas_rest='$result' Where ....
```

E para somar os valores que estão dentro de (duracao) na tabela assiste:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))

    {
        $hora= $row['Duracao'];
        $hora1 = explode(":",$hora);
        $min_hora1 = ($hora1[0] * 3600) + ($hora1[1] * 60);
        $total=$total+$min_hora1;
    }   

    $hora = floor($total / 3600);

    $total = $total - ($hora * 3600);

    $min = floor($resultado / 60)/10;

    $min=str_replace(".","",$min);

    if(strlen($min)==1){
      $min=$min."0";
    }

    $result=$hora.":".$min;
```

Comment: huahuahua, mudou para horas_dadas?

Comment: então, e como eu somo os valores que estão dentro de (duracao) na tabela assiste de acordo com o aluno 3?

Comment: vou ver aqui e te digo

Comment: Você tem Skype? talvez possamos conversar por lá, ai fica mais facil da gente conversar

Comment: Fiz os devidos testes e está funcionando bem. Tá na hora de mudar para mysqli pois mysql está descontinuado.

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com mysqli,não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer, mais posso estudar e ver como que é

Comment: muito simples, vc vai ver

Comment: Seus problemas foram resolvidos? marca a resposta como aceita :)

Comment: Leo, me responde uma pergunta aqui, agora a soma e subtração estão acontecendo, mas o valor está saindo somente com 1 digito antes  e depois dos dois pontos, vou postar aqui pra vc ver

Comment: $show_qtd_horas = '8';
$result_duracao = '4:57';
$Horas_rest = $show_qtd_horas; 
$soma = $result_duracao;



Resultado do echo

3:3

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55085/discussion-between-william-de-paula-and-leo-caracciolo).